# Any other way than Babel package?

Tags: babel, languages, polish

I have a complex PhD thesis temlate. I need to include a polish (second) abstract, but the hyphenation look terrbile. All the rest of the document is in english. When I try Babel package, Im getting an option clash.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english,polish}{babel}
```

is also not working:

> "! LaTeX Error: Command `\lll' already defined."

Comment: I do not have any experience with Polish typesetting. Have you checked http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-polish? You probably also want to give http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia and LuaTeX a try.

Comment: I cannot change to LuaTeX  now, it is too late for this. I have >100 pages...

Comment: Well, I successfully migrated a 300+ pages project from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. It was not that much work. But this is up to you. If it is only a short text, you could try to do the hyphenation by yourself. Sometimes this is even faster than looking for an clever solution.

Comment: @CampanIgnis: Why do you think that with luatex it will be easier to resolve an option clash error?

Comment: @Aleksander You should show a small but complete document (your preamble + some hello world text). Option clash errors are easy to resolve but not if you don't see the code that triggers them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I am sorry. As far as I remember, he wanted a replacement for babel, so I suggested Polyglossia. As far as I know, Polyglossia is designed to work with LuaTeX and XeTeX.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer,
Im afraid it is too long ang most of it is in the .cls file.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/

Answer (score 10):

For mysterious reasons, `polish.ldf` has

```
\let\lll=\l \let\LLL=\L
\def\plll{\lll}
\def\pLLL{\LLL}
```

and, of course, this should be something like

```
\let\polish@l=\l \let\polish@L=\L
\def\plll{\polish@l}
\def\pLLL{\polish@L}
```

This is used in some places in order to restore the meaning in case something changed it.

Solution for your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\let\polish@l=\lll \let\polish@L=\LLL
\let\lll\relax \let\LLL\relax % undefine them
\def\plll{\polish@l}
\def\pLLL{\polish@L}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amssymb}
```

In your case, the `babel` package is loaded by the class, so the language options must be given to `\documentclass`:

```
\documentclass[
        12pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
        english, % ngerman for German
        polish,
        singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
        headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
\let\polish@l=\lll \let\polish@L=\LLL
\let\lll\relax \let\LLL\relax % undefine them
\def\plll{\polish@l}
\def\pLLL{\polish@L}
\makeatother
```

The rest is the same as in your code.

Comment: Thanx. I tried it, but got the same error. But in my case Im putting it to a long template and maybe this is the reason.

Comment: @Aleksander The `\makeatletter...\makeatother` part should go immediately after you load `babel`.

Comment: @egreg: Imho the class or preamble already loads babel and so there is an option clash.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer,
Yes, it is in the class as a required package. It is too long, so I uploaded a working example here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxo9brsfrcbk1ft/example.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Aleksander Added the code you should use